# How to increase memory use on run nativescript

Tags: node.js, nativescript

I running code nativescript code with command tns run android --bundle and its also run with memory 4096MB. My RAM is 16. Why can it run on 4 not over more?

"Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.

Searching for devices...

Running webpack for Android...
clean-webpack-plugin: P:...\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app*** has been removed.

File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

Starting type checking service...

Using 1 worker with 4096MB memory limit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This log is produced by the [`ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin).

Just open your `<projectRoot>/webpack.config.js` file and increase the [`memoryLimit` property in the `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin` initialization](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/blob/master/templates/webpack.typescript.js#L266).